# is Swift strictly enforcing Class in protocol vars?

Tags: swift, protocols, var, swift2

A protocol `P` requires a variable `v` of class `C`.

Class `X` implements protocol `P` declaring a variable `v` of class `C1` where `C1` extends `C`.

Here's the code:

```
import Foundation    

class C { }
class C1: C { }

protocol P {
    var v: C { get set }
}

class X: P {
    var v: C1

    init(withV v: C1) {
        self.v = v
    }
}
```

Xcode complaints with this error:

```
Type 'X' does not conform to protocol 'P'
Protocol requires property 'v' with type 'C'
Candidate has non-matching type 'C1'
```

Why is the compiler forcing me to match exactly the same type declared in the protocol?

Edit:

The exact same implementation in Obj-C compiles without errors or warnings

```
@interface C: NSObject
@end
@implementation C
@end

@interface C1: C
@end
@implementation C1
@end

@protocol P <NSObject>
    @property (nonatomic, strong) C *v;
@end

@interface X: NSObject <P>
    @property (nonatomic, strong) C1 *v;
@end
@implementation X
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't forcing you to match exactly, but it's forcing you to avoid runtime issues. Your setup can mean that you pass a reference to something claiming to conform to `P` but which doesn't actually conform. This is because `P` says that you can set `v` to any `C`, but `X` says you can set `v` to any `C1`.

So, if you were to create another subclass of `C`, `C2`, and try to use that, everything would fall apart.

I'd expect your obj-c example to complain that you haven't implemented or synthesised the property specified to exist in the protocol...

Comment: Obj-C doesn't complain at all, but i just figured out that the set in the protocol means that at runtime everyone can set `v` to a `C` class and `X` can fail accessing to `C` as if it was `C1`. Thanks for the answer.